# Generating secure crypto keys from random number

Tags: javascript, binary

In my webpage I'm retrieving random numbers from mouse movement to generate a safe crypto key to be use in AES-128 encryption, that is a 16 bytes long key.

So lets supouse I retrieve the number 0123456789012345, which is 16 bytes length, then I would convert each number into binary.

Problem is that for every unit/byte I only have 10 posibilities (0-9) when I could have 255 posibilites (0-255), this is where byte arrays come in handy.

So how can I take advantage of the 255 byte posibilities for each byte using the retrieved random number in a fast way? I guess maybe using a mathematical function that works the number while preventing it from going beyond 255, or something.